# How to handle child data collections

Tags: data-exchange-framework

Using Sitecore 9.0.1 and DEF 2.0.1, to process JSON from an API. This works well until I have child entities in the json.

E.g.

```
{

  "name": "XXX",
  "short_description": null,
  "description": null,
  "type": "destination",
  "childobject": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "YYY",
      "type": "AAA"

    },
    {
      "id" : "2"
      "name": "FFF",
      "type": "ASSSAA"
    }
  ]
}
```

My processor adds the parent object to IterableDataSettings with just the one row for the parent object. But how do I process childobjects ? It would seem they need to be added to a seperate IterableData set and pipeline but is that even possible in code?

My issues may stem from using a generic processor (ReadJsonDetailApiProcessor) that knows nothing about the "childobjects".

When I create an accessor for childobjects, could I use a custom Value Reader implementation ? But then again it would need to use a seperate pipeline

As you can tell, Im lacking clarity on how to do this at the moment

Comment: Why does pipeline step pass only parent object instead of all json?

Comment: Pipeline step does have all of the json but it's processed based on json key names and accessed via JSONPath. This works for simple types but not for the child objects. Im thinking I may need a CustomReader implementation for the childobject data accessor..

Comment: Hi @VladShpak. The pipeline step does have all the json. However, the child objects aren't mapped to any Sitecore items and Sitecore Item Field Value Accessor only allows a field name. It seems to me I would like to give the field value for childobject it's own Sitecore mapping and it's own resolution of a Sitecore item in the DEF, but I would need to configure the Sitecore template to use somewhere and that config for child objects doesnt seem to exist in DEF. Does that make any sense or am I completely off the track?

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this issue you have to deep dive into two Pipeline Steps that could help you.

---

**Resolve Sitecore Item Pipeline Step**

This Pipeline step has "Find Existing Item" section with two settings.

[image]

***Parent for Item*** - You have to specify the parent item in the content tree in order to pipeline step knows the main root location for resolved items. This setting uses for the first-level item. In your case under selected parent will be added items with mapped fields: name, short_description, description, type.

***Parent for Item Location*** - If a location is set, and the object at the location is a Sitecore item, this item is used as the parent instead of the item specified in Parent for Item. This setting can be used when you need resolve "childobjects". How it works. When the parent item was added/updated it's still in the context together with source object(json) and it means that you just can extract/get/copy childobjects from source and iterate them and for the resolver use this field to specify parent.

---

**Copy Object from Context to New Location Pipeline Step**

This Pipeline Step has "*Location Settings*" section.
You can use this pipeline step in order to extract/copy/get "childobjects".

[image]

***Source object location*** - to specify source object location. In your case to specify your json object location.

***Source Object value Accessor*** - Component used to read the source object from the object resolved from the source object location (if not set, the source object itself is used). In other words here accessor should be used that knows how to extract/get/read childobject from json/parentjson.

***Target Object Location*** - The object that is resolved is copied to this location. It means that object resolved from Source "Object value Accessor" will be copied to the specified location.

Now you should be able to iterate the childobjects.

***Example:***

[image]

Comment: Thanks Vlad. My existing Pipeline goes Resolve item => Apply Mappings => Update Sitecore. Would the new "Copy Object from Context to New Location Pipeline Step" go between Resolve item and Apply Mappings ? Where would the step for iterating the child data fit into this?

Comment: Also, do you know if ""Copy Object from Context to New Location Pipeline Step"" can be used to add to the mappings set up in Apply Mappings? This would be instead of a seperate pipeline step for iterating the child date

Comment: Should be similar as in option 2 https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/11711/consuming-a-restful-api-with-entity-relationships

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. How I see it.

Comment: Is there any documentation that explains exactly how to use the "Copy Object from Context to New Location Pipeline Step"? I need to do something similar to this and I really don't understand how to use a step of that type.  Is there any Sitecore documentation that explains all of the OOB step types and how to use them?

Comment: @CoreyBurnett There doesn't seem to be. I've found the best way is to decompile the assembly using dotPeek for example. A pain but it works..

Comment: @VladShpak Im now using "Copy Object from Context to New Location Pipeline Step" to iterate over my child objects (from json). But in my child objects mapping, I also need to get access to a value from the parent e.g. the "xxx" value for "name" on the parent. Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: @SteveWard If your parent, before you iterate children, was in "Pipeline Context Target" location, then while you iterate children in a separate pipeline you can get parent from "Pipeline Context Parent Target" location

Comment: Thanks @Vlad. I didnt realise you could have different data available in the different contexts. That opens things up a bit ..