# Resolve Multilanguage Sitecore Item Dictionary Pipeline Step does not take into account Parent for Item Location setting

Tags: data-exchange-framework

I have an issue with adding of child items under just created parent item. I am using an approach from [this post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12310/how-can-i-use-the-sitecore-data-exchange-framework-to-create-child-items-from-xm). However, I have an issue because I am **using multilanguage pipeline steps** (details below).

Env-nt:

```
Sitecore.NET 9.0.1 (rev. 171219)
Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1
```

Installed packages:

```
Data Exchange Framework SDK 2.0.1
Sitecore Provider for Data Exchange Framework 2.0.1(to store items in Sitecore)
```

My thoughts were following: if we already created a Parent, so we have Parent sitecore item in Target context. I want to use a Parent item as a parent for all its children. So, I set  "Pipeline Context Target" for "Parent for Item Location" field in Resolve Item Step.

[image]

However, it seems I don't have correct parent item. Error message in the log: Item was not saved. (id: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000, language: en).

I used dotPeek to check the code of processor **ResolveMultilanguageSitecoreItemDictionaryPipelineStep** (highlighted on the image above). It seems that we don't use "Parent for Item Location" field at all.

[image]

If we check the default pipeline step **ResolveSitecoreItemStepProcessor** then it seems OK.

[image]

As a workaround I will try to create my own processor (as a copy of existing one with some changes), but it would be great to get any suggestions/feed back from some of you as well.

Best regards,
Maxim

Comment: Is this question significantly different from this one? https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12310/how-can-i-use-the-sitecore-data-exchange-framework-to-create-child-items-from-xm

Comment: @MarkCassidy I guess the question should be something like "Resolve Multilanguage Sitecore Item Dictionary Pipeline Step does not take into account Parent for Item Location setting"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

we finally managed to solve this issue. Sitecore provided me with an official hotfix which I am using in Resolve Item/Update Item steps. 
If you can't ask Support for the help by some reason - then you can use hotfix provided by Vlad.

https://github.com/vladcheg/Sitecore.DataExchange.Providers.Sc.CustomHotfix

I used his solution with one small change:

[image: my changes]

I found that DEF is trying to find the plugin above in ResolveMultilanguagePipelineStep (if we have "Parent For Item Location" field set to "Pipeline Context Parent Temp Storage").

[image: data from dotPeek]

Hope it will be useful for some of you.